# Alarm Synchroniztion between two devices

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification, alarm

I am working on alarm app. I set the alarm (specific time) on one device.
This time is converted to GMT and send.

```
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]; 
NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];
```

On receiving side, i convert the time back to devices timezone

```
NSDate* localDateTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] sinceDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:_request[@"time"]]];
```

On both devices I create a local notification with alarmTime as the fireDate.

The problem is if the clock is not correct in any one of the device, local notification will be fired at different time and alarm will not play at same time.

On both devices i have also set the clock automatically and checked but some time there is a slight difference between 1 - 0.5 sec.

Please tell me how to sync the alarm.
Thanks

Comment: You should compare the local time on the device with the server time and save the offset.

Comment: But if we have slow internet, then even calling the Web Service can cause a delay of 1 sec or more, which will result in incorrect offset.

Comment: You could add the duration of the request to the offset, but I do not think it is that important.